# Проверка статуса картинки

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как проверить, загрузилась ли картинка или нет? Некоторые картинки не загружаются и хотелось бы их заменять на плэйсхолдер. Через запросы fetch, ajax и т.п не получится т.к Chrome не поддерживает CORS на локалхостах, через `new Image()` не получается сделать.

```js
img.src = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/do4Cb__WhlY/maxresdefault.jpg`;
img.onload = function () {
    if(this.width + this.height === 0) {
        this.onerror();
    }
}
img.onerror = function () {
    img.src = `http://localhost:4662/static/image/placeholder.png`;
}
```

Comment: Ну так и используй событие `onerror`, чем оно не угодило?

Comment: Я же написал что не получается сделать, даже `console.log` не выводится, может я конечно чет не так сделал

Comment: попробуй присваивать `src` **после** присваивания обработчиков событий

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как было в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1454217/441792) от Ивана Апелова, все видео по умолчанию загружается плэйсходером, склыдавем длину и ширину картинки смотрим ее размер, если картинка не равна 210 пикселям то меняем на фотку которая должна загрузится, она находится в `data-src`

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/do4Cb__WhlY/maxresdefault.jpg`

image.onload = function() {
    if(image.width+image.height !== 210) {
        $(`img[data-src="${image.src}"]`).attr("src", `${image.src}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Изначально нужно поставить всем картинкам плейсхолдеры. Сразу при загрузке страницы должен срабатывать скрипт, который поменяет атрибут src в img на нужные. Плейсхолдер не изменится до того момента как новое изображение не будет загружено. Обычно нужные пути вставляют в атрибут data-src, чтобы не путаться. Так что не нужно загружать ничего js-ом. Только ссылку поменять.